# Python string is null but also isn't None nor empty string

Tags: python, httprequest, webapp2

```py
class StartAnalysis(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        playlist = self.request.get('playlist')
        language = self.request.get('language')
```

If I make a POST request without this `playlist` field, then this happens:

```
>>> playlist
null
>>> type(playlist)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> playlist is None
False
>>> not playlist
False
>>> playlist == ''
False
>>> playlist == u''
False
```

How am I supposed to check that it's None? And why is it saying that it's null and not None?

I'm using AppEngine.

My javascript code making the POST request:

```js
let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
let url_id = params.get('id');
let url_language = params.get('language');
const url = 'http://localhost:8080/start-analysis?playlist=' + url_id + '&language=' + url_language;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(results) {
       ...
    },
    error: function(error) {
       ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this Python 2? Anyway, there is no null in Python, that's the string `"null"` but it indicates a larger problem that you're probably not deserializing the JSON properly

Comment: Yes it's Python 2.7. And your comment helped me figure it out. "null" is a string but I was using print statements so I didn't notice. The POST request was made in js with a fill-in-the-blank endpoint and I guess js inserts 'null' into the string instead of just an empty string for whatever reason. Thanks.

Comment: It probably doesn't insert the string "null", you're just taking the string literal version of the response. If you deserialize `null` from the JS side into a Python object, it would be converted to `None`

Comment: Oh, I forgot the other point I wanted to make. Unless you're _forced_ to use Python 2, then you really need to upgrade to Python 3. Python 2 has reached its end-of-life and is no longer supported

Comment: can you share with us your POST request? even you can use request.params instead request.get

Comment: I switched to using application/json instead of x-www-form-urlencoded as well as adding what I think you mean by "deserializing" (`JSON.stringify()` and `json.loads()`) and now python recognizes it as a Python object (either `None` or `''`). I also edited in the original POST request above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed to using `application/json` for the POST requests instead of the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and that seemed to fix the problem of the request sending the string `"null"` instead of just an empty string when one of the parameters was empty or missing.

```js
let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
let url_id = params.get('id');
let url_language = params.get('language');
const url = 'http://localhost:8080/start-analysis';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({'playlist': url_id,'language': url_language}),
    success: function(results) {
        ...
    },
    error: function(response, status, error) {
        ...
    }
});
```

And the backend receives it like:

```py
class StartAnalysis(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = json.loads(self.request.body)
        playlist = data['playlist']
        language = data['language']
```